# debootstrap fails with "Failed to retrieve InRelease"

Tags: linux, debian, rootfs

I have a Intel 64-bit machine running Linux mint 18.1 . On this machine, when I run the following command

```
sudo debootstrap --arch ia64 wheezy rootfs http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian
```

with the following errors :

```
W: cannot check release signature; keyring file not available /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg
I: Failed to retrieve InRelease
```

Now, I have a second machine with exactly similar hardware configurations, running Ubuntu 16.04. On this machine, I get the same error but it still continues and downloads the rootfs correctly.

What could be the reason? I tried copying the keyrings from the working machine to the failing machine, still no luck. Both the devices are sitting in the same network with same network configurations

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Those Debian Chroot's have [a lot of problems](https://www.google.com/search?q=debootstrap+jww). After they broke signing last year, enough was enough for me. I finally gave up on them. You might find [this page](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Debian_Chroot#Unknown_key_B4C86482705A2CE1) useful. They are basically my field notes when trying to setup and maintain a variety of them.

Comment: And to comment on `sudo debootstrap --arch ia64 ...` - As far as I know, there is no emulation for ia64. There are no hits for it when running [`update-binfmts --display | grep interpreter`](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Debian_Chroot#Debootstrap). You may need to test on real Itanium hardware. They call Itanium the Itanic because it sunk. Its hard to find the hardware in the field.

Answer (score -1):

I tried what you did with the LinuxMint 18.1 LiveCD, and deboostrap fails not on the message you quote, but on the chroot step.

You should use `--arch amd64` instead of `--arch ia64`.